# Swapping square matrices names in C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, swap

I have been looking for a way to swap the names between two matrices in C. I have 2 square size x size matrices. I make some operation to the one of them, I put the result in a cell in the other matrix, then I swap their names and I repeat.

Below I am giving my code

```
int main(void){
int const size = 1000;
int const steps = 10;
float A[size][size], B[size][size];
int i,j,k;
int t = 0;
double sum = 0;
double sum1 = 0;
int const ed = size - 1;
for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
    for(j = 0; j < size; ++j){// initialize the matrices
        A[i][j] = i+j;
        B[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){//find the sum of the values in the first matrix
    for(j = 0; j < size; ++j){
        sum = sum + A[i][j];
    }
}
printf("The total sum of the matrix 1 is %lf \n",sum);

for(k = 0; k < steps; ++k){//for each cell of the matrix A calculate the average of the values' of the cell and its surroundings and put it in the coresponding place in the matrix B and then copy matrix B to matrix A and repeat. There are special cases for the cells who are at the edges and the last or first row/column.
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < size; ++j){
            if(i==0){
                if(j==0)
                    B[i][j]=(A[0][0]+A[0][1]+A[0][ed]+A[1][0]+A[ed][0])/5.0;
                else if(j==ed)
                    B[i][j]=(A[0][ed]+A[0][0]+A[0][ed-1]+A[1][ed]+A[ed][ed])/5.0;
                else
                    B[i][j]=(A[0][j]+A[0][j+1]+A[0][j-1]+A[1][j]+A[ed][j])/5.0;
            }else if(i==ed){
                if(j==0)
                    B[i][j]=(A[ed][0]+A[ed][1]+A[ed][ed]+A[0][0]+A[ed-1][0])/5.0;
                else if(j==ed)
                    B[i][j]=(A[ed][ed]+A[ed][0]+A[ed][ed-1]+A[0][ed]+A[ed-1][ed])/5.0;
                else
                    B[i][j]=(A[ed][j]+A[ed][j+1]+A[ed][j-1]+A[0][j]+A[ed-1][j])/5.0;
            }else{
                if(j==0)
                    B[i][j]=(A[i][0]+A[i][1]+A[i][ed]+A[i+1][0]+A[i-1][0])/5.0;
                else if(j==ed)
                    B[i][j]=(A[i][ed]+A[i][0]+A[i][ed-1]+A[i+1][ed]+A[i-1][ed])/5.0;
                else
                    B[i][j]=(A[i][j]+A[i][j+1]+A[i][j-1]+A[i+1][j]+A[i-1][j])/5.0;
            }
        }
    }
    sum1 = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < size; ++j){
            sum1 = sum1 + B[i][j];
        }
    }
    t=t+1;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < size; ++j){
            A[i][j] = B[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("%lf \n",sum1-sum);
}
printf("The total sum of the matrix 2 is %lf \n",sum1);
printf("Number of steps completed: %i \n",t);
printf("Number of steps failed to complete: %i \n", steps-t);
return 0;
```

}

I have used the method of copying each time the one matrix to the other, but this is not efficient.

I have a hint that I should use pointers but I can not figure it out. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can swap the values of any two variables of the same type by assigning the value of the first to a temporary variable then assigning the value of the second to the first, then assigning the value of the temporary variable to the second:

```
int a = 2, b = 3, tmp;

tmp = a;
a = b;
b = tmp;
```

In particular, it works exactly the same when the variables are of pointer type, so

```
/* The matrices */
double one[3][3], another[3][3];

/* pointers to the matrices */
double (*matrix1p)[3] = one;
double (*matrix2p)[3] = another;
double (*tmp)[3];

/* ... perform matrix operations using matrix1p and matrix2p ... */

/* swap labels (pointers): */
tmp = matrix1p;
matrix1p = matrix2p;
matrix2p = tmp;

/* ... perform more matrix operations using matrix1p and matrix2p ... */
```

---

**Updated to clarify:**

`matrix1p` is initially an alias for `one`, and `matrix2p` is initially an alias for `another`.  After the swap, `matrix1p` is an alias for `another`, whereas `matrix2p` is an alias for `one`.  Of course, you can perform such a swap as many times as you want.  You cannot, however, swap `one` and `another` themselves, except via an element-by-element swap.

---

Note that this yields improved efficiency because pointers are quite small relative to the matrices themselves.  You don't have to move the elements of the matrices, but only to change which matrix each pointer refers to.

Comment: I am trying to understand your suggestion: After these doing these steps once, when I refer to element another[i][j] is it the same element of one[i][j] before the swapping?

Comment: @user2149122, no.  The elements of `one` and `another` do not move, which is exactly the point.  Also, it is not the names "one" and "another" that are being swapped; rather, the names "matrix1p" and "matrix2p" that are (effectively) swapped.  More technically, it is which matrix each of those latter names refers to that is swapped.  There is no efficiency available to be gained if you have to move the matrix elements.

Comment: Ok then. One more question for you: How can I access a specific element one[i][j] using the pointer?

Comment: @user2149122, given the declarations as I presented them, while `one` is aliased by `matrix1p`, you can access `one[i][j]` as `matrix1p[i][j]`.  It's as simple as that.  Likewise, while `one` is aliased by `matrix2p`, you can access `one[i][j]` as `matrix2p[i][j]`.

Comment: I have posted my code in my question to make it better to understand. It does not matter what happens in the values of matrix B when a step is completed, because they are gonna be replaced by the averages of the next step. (Another minnor problem is that this code does not work in the aspect that the sum of the values of the cells should be constant, but when I run it there are some small diviations. If you could take a look I would be greatfull). My question is how do I use pointers to get the same result, without having to copy each time one matrix to the other. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user2149122, I have already explained that if you refer to your matrices via pointers then you can change which matrix each pointer refers to.  Such an approach can address your issue, regardless of whether you want a complete swap or whether you want to change the referent only of one pointer.  Some variation on that is the only possible alternative to copying the matrix elements.

Comment: @user2149122, as for arithmetic deviations, you are performing floating-point arithmetic, which is inexact.  The same computation should always produce the same result, but the relevant definition of "same" is quite narrow: identical operations performed on identical operands in identical order.  In particular, the only algebraic rearrangement guaranteed to not change the result is commuting the operands of `+` or `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should definitely use pointers, for example:

```
void swap (int*** m1, int*** m2)
{
    int** temp;
    temp = *m1;
    *m1 = *m2;
    *m2 = temp;
}
```

And then invoke:

```
int m1[5][5] = 0;
int m2[5][5] = 0;
swap (&m1, &m2);
```

Comment: That looks convenient, but won't actually work.  (a) You are passing `int (*)[5][5]` to a function that expects `int ***` and the type mismatch matters, and (b) you can't change an array like that.

Comment: Thank you for your effort Michal, but it does not work due to the mismatch.